# "Can't resolve all parameters…" with @Optional decorator

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, swagger-codegen

I'm getting a strange DI error. This is a piece of auto-generated code from swagger-codegen - I cannot change it. I'm trying to inject this service. However when I run `ng build --aot` I get the `Can't resolve all parameters...` DI error.

I tried to remove toe @Optional parameter altogether and it seems to work. So this seems to be the culprit.

My question: Why am I getting an error for not providing the parameter if it is optional? I'm also interested how I would go about if I wanted to actually inject this parameter as it is a primitive type.

```
@Injectable()
export class MyApi {
    protected basePath = 'https://localhost/';
    public defaultHeaders : Headers = new Headers();

    constructor(protected http: Http, @Optional() basePath: string) {
        if (basePath) {
            this.basePath = basePath;
        }
    }
}
```

**NOTE**: The answers of @Nildari and @PierreDuc will probably be what most people may be looking for. However, I'm looking for a solution which won't change the original implementation as it is auto-generated.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use an [`InjectionToken`](https://angular.io/api/core/InjectionToken):

```
export const BASE_PATH: InjectionToken<string> = new InjectionToken<string>('basePath');

// note that the string value `basePath` is just a description of the `InjectionToken` 
// and not actually the base path.
```

The advantage of using an `InjectionToken`

Then you need to add an provide object to your `providers` array of your [`NgModule`](https://angular.io/api/core/NgModule):

```
@NgModule({
    //...
    providers: [
        {provide: BASE_PATH, useValue: '/'}
    ]
})
```

Then you can inject this provider in your service using [`@Inject`](https://angular.io/api/core/Inject):

```
constructor(protected http: Http, @Inject(BASE_PATH)basePath: string) {
    if (basePath) {
        this.basePath = basePath;
    }
}
```

And you can add the `@Optional` decorator if you feel like it.. but if you add it to your providers array, it will always be found

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, however I'm looking for a solution which won't change the original impplementation as it is auto-generated.

Comment: @mode777 then this is a problem with `swagger-codegen`. DI doesn't work with `string` in combination with `@Optional()` anymore in later angular versions :)

Comment: this seems to be the answer i was looking for. I'll have a look at the github issues

Answer (score 2):

If you want to inject `basePath` into `MyApi` service class you can do it like below

Add some 'path' provider to app providers and use `@Inject('path')` parameter decorator to inject it into `MyApi` class

```
@Injectable()
export class MyApi {
    protected basePath = 'https://localhost/';
    public defaultHeaders : Headers = new Headers();

    constructor(protected http: Http, @Inject('path') basePath: string) {
        if (basePath) {
            this.basePath = basePath;
        }
    }
}
```

Than in the bootstrap file of your application (@NgModule)

```
bootstrap('name of your app.component class', [
  MyApi, 
  provide('path', { useValue: 'any value which you want to inject'})
]);
```

you can use `@Optional` parameter to make the dependency optional.

Comment: I had to remove accepted answer as this answer wont work for me: As I said the implementation of MyApi is created by swagger-codegen. If I make changes to this implementation it will be overwritten next time I run swagger-codegen. I'm looking for a solution that works without changing the implementation of `MyApi`

Comment: @mode777 not an issue my answer was in general to angular , not specific to swagger

Comment: @Nildari: I added a note to the original post referencing your answer as it might be what most people are actually looking for.

Comment: @mode777 may be you can find the solution in github under swagger-codegen

Answer (score 0):

**There is a 'sort-of-a-bug' where the location of the 'unresolvable' dependency can be wrongly be reported:**

I have a `BusyTaskService` which I use in several places to indicate something is loading.

I was getting this error:

```
main.js:54282 NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[SupportQuestionComponent -> BusyTaskService]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[SupportQuestionComponent -> BusyTaskService]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for BusyTaskService!
```

Which literally made no sense give that `BusyTaskService` has no dependencies and the component was providing the service to itself!

```
...
  providers: [ BusyTaskService ]
})
export class QuickSupportQuestionComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(@Optional() private busyTaskService: BusyTaskService,
```

So how is this possible?

I looked everywhere else in my code and found a second service that also used `BusyTaskService` but without `@Optional()` and *that* service had no parent in the DI tree that was providing an instance. Once I made the service optional for this second service everything worked.

So if you get the following and it makes no sense:

> 1. Search everywhere for where you used the service and make sure it
>    has a provider in the DI tree.
> 2. Comment out the `@Optional` decorator, re-compile and look to see if
>    you get a different error message.